# Start Tor Browser from CLI in Mac OSX

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I want to start the Tor Browser to a specific url from command-line but I don't found any way to do that.

On Linux, i know the "start-tor-browser" script exist but I don't found it on Mac OS X (10.10) after install the Tor Browser Bundle ([here](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads))

In the Tor Browser.app I found a "firefox" command, but this start a regular firefox...

So, i look for something like this :

```
tor-browser https://www.example-url.com
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tor server you can start by simply typing: `tor`.

Web browser by:

```
/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox http://example.com/
```

If you're using it quite often, you can make an alias, such as:

```
alias tor-browser="/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox"
```

and add it into your `~/.bashrc` file.